# Javascript minification and shrinking variables with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, obfuscation, packer

I've been looking around SO for a JavaScript obfuscation script of some kind, note that I'm not looking for a compressor, I need an obfuscation script/code that will shrink the JavaScript files I have in PHP (not in JavaScript) for production reasons.

I've heard about Minify, I've used it a couple times, works great but it doesn't obfuscate my JS code, simply that is all I need to have, think like the [Dean Edwards packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) but without packing it, just the shrink variables mode in PHP instead of JS.

**EDIT**: My mistake, I understood "obfuscate" wrongly, I mean minification on the JS code - shrinking variable names and removing whitespace, etc. Minify is the closest I got to, but it does not shrink variables.

Is there one out there?

Comment: Just FYI: Obfuscating code usually makes it larger.  Shrinking variable names is part of minifying code, not obfuscating it.

Comment: Try google, gives you tons of obfuscators "out there".

Comment: I agree, this is question for google, not SA...

Comment: @Rocket My bad, read my edit.

Comment: Do you have the option of utilizing the Closure Compiler JAR through PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec('java.exe -jar compiler.jar --js pre.js --manage_closure_dependencies true --js_output_file end.js');
```

---

```
exec('java.exe -jar yuicompressor.jar pre.js  -o end.js');
```

use:

google closure compiler AND 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 1):

Our [ECMAScript Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/ECMAScriptObfuscator.html) probably does what you want.   In particular, it will find JavaScript chunks in PHP files and obfuscate/minify depending on what you want.

Comment: You recommended a paid version. Perhaps it would be nice if there was a free script apart from your obfuscator.

Comment: You asked if there was one out there.  There are others that work on plain Javascript. There are others that work with HTML but I have no idea if they work with PHP scripts, which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for.  And I dont' know if you'll be able to find a solution that does it better than Google: http://code.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question -- but it needs an updated answer, as there are now PHP implementations of jsMin

eg:  http://wonko.com/post/a_faster_jsmin_library_for_php

Note:  When you say "shrink variables" it's important to clarify:  Most minifiers will only shrink local variables within functions, but leave globals and function names -- as renaming those would likely break interoperability with the page / DOM elements / other scripts, etc.